# Selenium "import 'selenium' could not be resolved" - "no module named selenium"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Tengo un problema con selenium y no encuentro solución por ningún lugar. No se si el problema es que no encuentra el selenium, y si es así no se que hacer, busqué por todas partes.

Lo instalé con el **cmd** con el **pip** (estoy trabajando desde python) desde mi usuario y desde System32 para ver si ese era el problema. La carpeta con el driver del selenium está directamente en el disco C, estoy siguiendo un tutorial y a esa persona y todas las demás las sirve, ese no creo que sea el problema, se ve así:

```
from selenium import webdriver # acá me tira el error 'import 'selenium' could not be resolved'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\dchrome\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("http://python.org")
```

Y ya cuando intento ejecutarlo, en consola me dice `no module named selenium`. El driver de chrome que me descargué es el 113 y estoy en la versión 113.

Comment: Me suena a que tienes varias versiones de Python en ese equipo. Posiblemente el IDE esté anclado a una de esas versiones, entonces desde cmd se hace una cosa y desde el IDE dice que está pasando otra. Prueba poniendo un `import sys` y luego `print(sys.executable)` y ejecuta el script desde el IDE y desde el cmd a ver si estamos hablando del mismo intérprete.

Comment: tenías razon, pero aún cambiandolos a la misma versión, creando un entorno virtual nuevo e instalando selenium de nuevo, sigue diciendo lo mismo...